# configuring Expect coding to save file with date stamp

Tags: expect

I got a simple expect script that I have configured to pull files from a remote system of mine and to save them to my linux box which works great! however every time I run the script it will auto over ride the previous file it saved from the last time I ran the script. Is there a way to add in a way to save the file + (date & time stamp) ?

This is the code I am working with:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn scp "username@IP_of_device:" /Linux_box
#######################
expect {
  -re ".*es.*o.*" {
    exp_send "yes\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  -re ".*sword.*" {
    exp_send "PASSWORD\r"
  }
}
interact
```

Comment: I think you'll have to pull the files over one-by-one if you want to give each a new name on the local system.

Comment: Well I am only pulling a selected file over and I'd wanna have it as: file_name-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set remote the_file_name
set date [timestamp -format %Y-%m-%d]
set local "$remote-$date"
spawn scp "username@IP_of_device:$remote" $local
```

ref: http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html